# Sum over n-tuples with total sum equal to k

Tags: loops, math, sum, combinatorics

I want to sum over tuples of length n, i.e. I have a vector (m_1,...,m_n) where mi is an integer greater or equal to zero with the constraint that the sum of all vector elements is equal to k.

What is the most efficient way to implement this?

My naive approach would be to iterate through all combinations with m_i between 0 and k and check if they satisfy the criterion, but this seems inefficient.

For instance, if k=2 and n=2, then

(2,0),(1,1),(0,2) would be the possible values of m1,m2 that I would like to have. Is there a way to generate these numbers efficiently (I don't necessarily have to store them all in an array, but I want to iterate over all possible combinations)

Comment: So you just want m1+m2+...m_n = k, mi an integer >= 0? So this is just a counting problem, count how many solutions there are? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I want to sum over all possible combinations of this, i.e. evaluate a sum_{m1+...+mn=k} f(m1,..,mn)

Comment: "I want to sum over tuples of length n" Why? You already said sum to be fixed to k. What is there to sum?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, random stuff I deleted.

If you look at [FXT book/library](https://www.jjj.de/fxt/fxtpage.html#fxtbook) by J.Arndt, there is on page 342 section 16.3 "Partition into m parts"

Here is algorithm and reference to the code to generate exactly m-vector of partitioning of n.

You'll probably need to modify it, he doesn't have bins with zeros, starts with ones.

And some thoughts on the matter. n is sum, and you have k bins. Start with |n|0|...|0| combination. Define operation "distribute 1" which is take one from the leftmost bin and distribute it into all other bins.

E.g. D1(|n|0|...|0|)=tuple(|n-1|1|...|0|, ..., |n-1|0|...|1|)

Then you apply D1() to the tuple, and get tuple of tuples. And so on and so forth, till first bin is exhausted.

You could think this as a tree:

root                                              |n|0|...|0|

D1 applied once, k-1 leaves |n-1|1|...|0| ... |n-1|0|...|1|

Next tree level, D1 applied once to previous level, each node getting k-1 children.

THe only thing left is how to traverse it - DFS, BFS, or anything else from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal